# move_base start position is off the global costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, position, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

after following this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Global_Configuration and run rviz when I try to give a 2d nav goal in the map the shell output this error:

> The robot's start position is off the
> global costmap. Planning will always
> fail, are you sure the robot has been
> properly localized?

someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thanks for your attention

EDIT 1: thanks @ayush_dewan for your answer, I checked my tf tree typing

> rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree

[image: image description]

and the rqt_graph

[image: image description]

I see that the map server is not connected with the main tree but it is in the tf tree.

I don't understand if is a map trouble (type of the map, resolution,...) or a tf issue.

Edit 2: Tryed the tf_echo command with the following output:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link
At time 1374093690.903
- Translation: [-0.002, 0.006, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.003, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.005]

rosrun tf tf_echo /map /odom
At time 1374093829.437
- Translation: [-0.224, 0.066, 0.000]

rosrun tf tf_echo /odom /base_link
At time 1374093875.303
- Translation: [0.224, -0.051, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.022, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.045]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.020, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -0.039]
```

it seems to me that all is going well, or better no error is coming out.

Could you please specify a little more where the issue could be?
Thanks

EDIT 3:thanks @ahendrix, this is my map.yalm code

```
image: map01.png
resolution: 0.02
origin: [-5.0, -5.0, 0.0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

and this the Rviz output
[image: image description]

I hope this could be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66399/move_base-start-position-is-off-the-global-costmap/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-08**:
Hello Daniel,
Did you solve this problem? I have an identical problem too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using rviz to command the navigation stack? If not, you may want to open rviz and set a starting pose for the robot that is on the map. Take a look at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

If that doesn't work, can you post the size and resolution of your map?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-07-18**:
I'm using Rviz, set the 2D pose estimete and when I try to set the 2D nav goal the error appears. I download a test map from somewhere, in the last edit of the question you will find the map.yalm code

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-18**:
How big is your robot's footprint?

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-07-18**:
Something like 500 x 450 mm, I created the robot model in solidworks and exported in ros by passing and scaling in blender

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-18**:
You may want to enable a display of your robot's footprint (add a Polygon display to rviz) and make sure the entire footprint fits on the map.

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-07-18**:
Thanks for your answer, I added the display and all the footprint (a 50cm diameter circle) fits inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to check the the TF tree and see the position of ur robot with respect to a fixed frame which is either map or world and check whether all transformation have been defined correctly or not.

Ur odom id defined in correct frame. Echo /odom and see the position of robot or use
tf_echo to check the transformation values between map and base_link, map and odom, odom and base_link.

Using this u might be able to debug where transformation is going wrong.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Since all the transformation looks good, one thing you can try is to check the frame id attached to goal position...maybe that could help.

PS:add terminal output of tf_echo

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1